# Stuck on a program involving lists, sentences and positions in lists

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I am creating a program that identifies individual words in a sentence and prints out the position of the word. For example, the sentence:  "I LOVE TO CODE CODE I LOVE" should output

"I LOVE TO CODE

1 2 3 4 4 1 2"

I can do the numbers/positions but I cannot get it to identify the individual words. Can yo help me? Could you also help me improve my code? Thanks.

Here is my code:

```
sentence = input("What is your sentence?: ")
sentence = sentence.split() 
positions = [0]
for count, i in enumerate(sentence): 
    if sentence.count(i) < 2:
        positions.append(max(positions) + 1)
    else:
        positions.append(sentence.index(i) +1)
positions.remove(0)
file = open("positions.txt","w")
positions = " ".join(map(str, positions))
file.write(positions)
file.close()
```

Comment: I recommend you to post this in [CodeReview SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 1):

I now realize that this structure is very similar to what @hsfzxjy wrote. This code doesn't throw a TypeError, though :

```
from collections import OrderedDict

sentence = "I LOVE TO CODE CODE I LOVE"

positions = OrderedDict()

def get_word_index(word, index, positions):
    position = positions.get(word)
    if position:
        return str(position)
    else:
        positions[word] = index
        return str(index)

indices = [get_word_index(word, index, positions) for index, word in enumerate(sentence.split(), 1)]
print ' '.join(positions.keys())
# "I LOVE TO CODE"
print ' '.join(indices)
# "1 2 3 4 4 1 2"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sentence = input("What is your sentence?: ")
words = sentence.split()
unique_words=[]
for i in words:
    if i not in unique_words:
        unique_words.append(i)
print unique_words
indexes=[]
for i in words:
    for j in range(0,len(unique_words)):
        if i==unique_words[j]:
            indexes.append(j+1)
print indexes
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import OrderedDict

sentence = input("What is your sentence?: ")
words = sentence.split()
indices = OrderedDict()
results = []
index = 1

for word in words:
    if word not in indices:
        indices[word] = index
        index += 1
    results.append(indices[word])

print(' '.join(indices.keys()))
print(' '.join(results))
```